# How do I wait for other events in Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Kotlin, using Coroutines, Lets say I have a job that starts on a click of a button, and shouldn't end until the activity's `onStop` is called.

Something that looks like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    CoroutineScope(...).launch{
        print("Button clicked")

        // How to wait for "onStop()" ?

        print("Activity stopped")
    }
}
```

The above scenario is just an example of a general need to incorporate 
asynchronous events that come from within an SDK in the form of a function invocation (`onStop()`).

How should it be done? Thank you :]

Comment: Why exactly do you need the coroutine to "stay alive"? What does it do that makes any difference between being waiting or being done? I guess the role of that coroutine is probably what should constrain it to stay alive, not some artificial `join()` call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would create a special channel for a button, than send something to it from `onStop(0)` and wait for it in your code:

```
val onStopChannel = Channel<Int>()

fun onStop() {
    onStopChannel.offer(0)
}

button.setOnClickListener {
    CoroutineScope(...).launch{
        print("Button clicked")

        onStopChannel.receive()

        print("Activity stopped")
    }
}
```

Any other observable could also work.

Answer (score 5):

To address the question of:

> a general need to incorporate asynchronous events that come from within
>   an SDK in the form of a function invocation

I would like to add that the standard library's way of integrating asynchronous callbacks or futures from another library or API that doesn't use coroutines into your own code that does use coroutines is the `suspendCoroutine` function. It suspends the execution of the current coroutine, takes a non-suspending lambda in which you register your callbacks/listeners, which when called will tell the coroutine via a `Continuation` object to resume execution of the suspending function with a particular value or exception obtained from the callback.

For example, in the case of a network request:

```
suspend fun useValueFromApiCall(apiCall: Call<Thing>) {
    val myThing: Thing = suspendCoroutine<Thing> { continuation ->
        apiCall.enqueue(object: Callback<Thing> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Thing>, response: Response<Thing>) {
                continuation.resume(response.body()) // assign response.body() to myThing
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Thing>, t: Throwable) {
                continuation.resumeWithException(t) // throw t
            }
        })
    }
    // coroutine will suspend execution until the API call returns and
    // either myThing contains the response or an exception was thrown
    myThing.doSomething()
}
```

[Here is a snippet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8&t=846s) of a talk explaining what's going on here quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I would make my job wait with `join()` function and then cancel it in `onStop()` callback.
Something like:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var job: Job = Job()
    private val mainDispatchersContext = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    private val coroutineContext = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainDispatchersContext.launch {
            doJob()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun doJob() {
        coroutineContext.launch {
            // do something
            Log.v(TAG, "Job started")
            job.join()
            Log.v(TAG, "This line is not executed")
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        job.cancel()
        Log.v(TAG, "Job end")
    }

    companion object{
        const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }
}
```